# Having trouble passing arguments to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having trouble with this python subroutine ...

```
def make_1024 ( src, tgt ):
    print "/usr/bin/convert %s -background none -gravity center -extent '1024x500!' %s" % ( src, tgt )
    rc = call ( ["/usr/bin/convert", src, "-background",  "none",  "-gravity", "center", "-extent", "'1024x500!'", tgt] )
    print "rc is %d" % rc
```

... the output I get is ...

```
rc is 1
```

... and no 1024x500 file gets created.  I cannot figure out why.  I suspect there has to be a problem with the `"'1024x500!'"` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running you code, imagemagick gives the traceback:

```
convert: invalid argument for option `-extent': '1024x500!' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1429.
```

It is the quotes you put around the extent value

```
from subprocess import call

def make_1024 ( src, tgt ):
    print "/usr/bin/convert %s -background none -gravity center -extent 1024x500! %s" % ( src, tgt )
    rc = call ( ["/usr/bin/convert", src, "-background",  "none",  "-gravity", "center", "-extent", "1024x500!", tgt] )
    print "rc is %d" % rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
  make_1024(src="usage.jpg", tgt="test.jpg")
```

More specifically, `-extent "'1024x500!'"` and `"1024x500!"`. If this doesn't work you'll have to give more details on the traceback.

Comment: I have to wait a minute :) but I will

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a metacharacter in the shell; you might need to escape it e.g., using single quotes if you run the command that contains it via the shell.

`subprocess.call`does not invoke the shell by default therefore you don't need to escape `!`, moreover you should remove the unnecessary single quotes (there is no shell to strip them from the argument).

You could use `shlex.split()` to see how to convert a shell command (string) into a command arguments list that you can pass to `subprocess.call`:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("echo 'abc!'")
['echo', 'abc!'] #NOTE: no embed quotes
```